how to check the multi remote repo new commit when using git commit
I have a project with multi repo, when I commit with one of them, I just want to make sure each of the repo are newest, because the repo have some dependencies, I want to fetch all repo changes and make sure the build process works fine.
how to check each of the local repo newest or not before git commit?

Are you using submodules or something else?

no, just multipule git repo. but it contains submodule in each git repo
